# How to hide elements and reserve its space in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to hide elements in UWP but i can't reserve its space.

I've tried to change Visibility but there is no option to set **`Visibility`** to `Hidden`.

I can only set **`Visibility`** to `Visible` or `Collapsed`.

Would anyone know how to do this in UWP?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One solution is to modify the brush to be empty when the control is disabled.**

If it is a general control, you can modify the style of the control with `VisualStateManager` when it is disabled.

Take the button control as an example.

1. Override the style of the button control, and modify the brush to be empty in `<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">`.

```
<Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}"/>
            ...
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             ...
```

---

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" x:Name="myButton" .../>
```

2. When you need to hide it, set the control to Disabled.

   ```
   myButton.IsEnabled = false;
   ```

Comment: Thanks. We can make a new visual state and goto our new state from code behind.